# How to get alerted if childed has been added MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, backend

I'm building a PHP application that uses a MySQL database. However, this database is shared between many devices like iPhones using an app built with swift that also connects to the same database and the same principle applies to android apps. So I would like to know how to alert all devices connected to the database that a new entry was made so they can all update their tables, this entry can be done by any of the connected devices. Basically the same thing the Firebase does with the `on_child_added`. I used to use Firebase and it worked fine, but the web application was made using Java Script and now I need to use PHP, as it turns out using Firebase and PHP is a pain even with [Firebase admin SDK for PHP](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php), so I need to make this change. Any resources are appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I would leave the database out of this.  Whenever your webapp gets ready to write the record, or maybe after it has been written, then send a notification to the various devices.

Comment: You need a combination of JavaScript and PHP. Web servers don’t, by and large, _push_ data out. They are meant to respond to a request and then close the connection. At the client end, the usual approach is periodically check back with the server to see whether anything’s changed. That’s called __polling__. Using JavaScript to keep in touch with the web server is called __Ajax__.

Comment: But wouldn't that make my application slow?